Confused about this free body diagram
In this question

I was confused when I saw the solution

Why do we make the FBD like the right one instead of the one on the left. Isn't the mgcostheta acting on the wedge an external force?
I would appreciate your help

Systems can be defined in several different ways, and you can reach the same conclusion. If the block isn't sliding down the ramp, the block and ramp can be treated as one object with only the tension in the rope being an external force, or the ramp by itself can be considered one object which has the normal force of the block and the tension acting on it. If I pull on a chain of blocks connected by ropes, I can analyze each block individually having one forward tension and one backward tension, or I can simply say the chain of blocks is one object with my external force acting on it.
